# problemas al cambiar el tamaño del jframe vuelve asu estado de inicio java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola a todos soy nuevo en esto al momento de hacer el diseño tengo unos problemas y no se por que pasa esto, primero hice un menu deslizable el problema que tengo es que al momento de cambiar el tamaño del frame el menu vuelve a estar como antes, pasa lo mismo con el internalframe no se cual puede ser el problema si alguien sabe porfavor una ayuda[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgAh9.png)[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxkQk.png)

Comment: Hola Albin. ¿estas usando Swing, SWT o algún otro framework? Que usas para el menú deslizable podrias colocar código del listener del cambio de tamaño de la pantalla y de la creación del menú deslizable

Comment: Si es SWT hice creando una clase

Comment: public static void subir( final int tamaño, final long retardo, final int salto, final JComponent componente) {
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          for (int i = 0; i >= tamaño; i += salto) {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(retardo);
              componente.setLocation(componente.getX(), componente.getY()-salto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } 
          } 
        }
      }).start();
  }

Comment: El frame esta en undecorated y utilice una clase component resizer

Comment: ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
cr.registerComponent(this);

Comment: tambien pasa esto al maximizar

Comment: Desactive el undecorated y sigue lo mismo